# Labeling layer with two attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, fields-attributes

I use the QGIS version 3.28.4-Firenze and I have the following question:
How can I label a polygon layer with two attributes, where the two attribute labels should look different (color, shape, size) and should be located exactly horizontal next to each other, but outside of the geometries I will label?

Does anyone have an idea how it could work?

this is how it looks at the moment
[image: this is how it looks at the moment]

it should look like that

[image: it should look like that]

---

"A simple option would be to use 'offset from point' for label placement and then use different offset distances for each label."

I tried this option. You can see the result in the first picture.
I was hoping to do it without Python, but maybe I should give it an try, or someone else knows a way to make the two attributes line up horizontally.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately my problem cannot be solved with the help of the videos. It is more complex than what is shown in the videos.

Answer (score 2):

To get two labels you can use rule based labelling, and do not any filter for each rule, i.e. all features for each. You can style each differently.

Label placement is more tricky.

A simple option would be to use 'offset from point' for label placement and then use different offset distances for each label.

I haven't tried more complex solutions. is there a QGIS  expression to find the position of a features labels? If not [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394275/getting-label-geometry-using-pyqgis-3) might help with a Python route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression to format your labels.

[image]

Rightclick on your layer and choose *Properties*. Go to the tab *Labels*.

[image]

- In the dropdown-menu select *Single Label*s.
- Check *Allow HTML formating*
- Click on the *expression butto*n next to Value
- Add an expression, the basics: concatenate values from 2 fields separated by ' - '

`"Field1" || ' - ' || "Field2"`

- style your label with whatever color, width, etc. using html

`'<h style="color:red;">'  || "Field1" || '</h>'  || '- ' || '<h style="color:yellow;">'  || "Field2" || '</h>'`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the text for the two labels, then they will always be plotted together, and you will not need two labels.